# allow client coder to post json and get a full view back from web service

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I wrote a scheduling app in laravel 5 that basically builds some json from local storage and sends this to the controller and then the view.  the view is mostly javascript that parses the json and builds the schedule.  I would like to extend this to allow a client coder to generate their own json and post that to my app and have my app send them a full view / schedule back.

I'm using php 7 and the php -S options to bring up 2 servers - one hosting the main schedule that i have and one hosting the client test code that posts to the schedule.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$uri ='/api/clientJSON'; 
$uri_token ='eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZSIsImlhdCI6MTQ1Njg0NDI1NiwiZXhwIjoxNDU2ODQ3ODU2LCJuYmYiOjE0NTY4NDQyNTYsImp0aSI6IjI2ODZjZWIwNjI2ZDVmZWE1YmVlZjMwNzM0ZDhkMzZmIn0.hWrIGNGLlIHOLP9FltefsN066WOHpGTm2SmsF6feAsI'; 
$calendarJson = '{"auth":"test"}';

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000',
    'timeout'  => 2.0,
]);


$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
    'query'=>['token' => $uri_token],
    'form_params' => [
        'calendarJson' => $calendarJson
    ]
]);

echo $response->getBody();
```

this issue seems to be that while the body does echo out, its only pulling in the html page and all the dependent js / css files are not loaded.  I'm clearly missing something fundamental about building my web service.  Can someone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 1):

While Guzzle is a PHP HTTP Client, it is not a web browser.  As such it will perform HTTP requests, but it will not parse the response to determine if or what other files need to be downloaded to view the content properly.

As observed, if a request is actioned, and the response contains references for externally stored javascript, or CSS files, they will not be requested.

For years the internet has been very good at blurring the lines between content and presentation.  As a service provider, you are interested in the content obtained from external sources, not how those external sources present it.

Comment: So I need to find a way to make a manual post to the page and echo that out to the browser right?